# How to decode a REG_BINARY date from Windows registry?

Tags: windows, date, format, registry, decode

I'm trying to decode a date encoded as a REG_BINARY in the Windows registry. Specifically this date:

```
SignaturesLastUpdated    REG_BINARY    720CB9EBE8CBCE01
```

which should in 2013.

Any idea how to manually decode it? (i.e. without using any built-in C# or C++ library)

Comment: The value is far too large to represent a time in the common Windows formats, 100 nanoseconds is the smallest time unit in common use.  This is most likely intentionally encrypted.  You'll know for sure when the programmer that wrote the code, the one that *knows*, is not responding to your support requests.

Comment: There is no standard for storing dates in the registry. You will have to check the documentation for that registry key. It should explain what the format is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [FILETIME structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-filetime) which is defined as:

> Contains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond
>   intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct _FILETIME {
  DWORD dwLowDateTime;
  DWORD dwHighDateTime;
} FILETIME, *PFILETIME, *LPFILETIME;
```

> Members
>
> dwLowDateTime 
>   The low-order part of the file time.
>
> dwHighDateTime 
>   The high-order part of the file time.

And here is how it can be converted to Unix time (in Go):

```
type Filetime struct {    
    LowDateTime  uint32    
    HighDateTime uint32    
}

// Nanoseconds returns Filetime ft in nanoseconds
// since Epoch (00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970).    
func (ft *Filetime) Nanoseconds() int64 {    
    // 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601    
    nsec := int64(ft.HighDateTime)<<32 + int64(ft.LowDateTime)    
    // change starting time to the Epoch (00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970)    
    nsec -= 116444736000000000    
    // convert into nanoseconds    
    nsec *= 100    
    return nsec    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I no longer need this but could be useful to others.